# Как запретить мутирование основного массива js

Tags: javascript

как сделать, чтобы основной массив store не мутировал?

```
function bubbleSort(stats) {
  for (let i = 0; i < stats.length - 1; i++) {
    const tmp = stats[i];

    if (stats[i].size > stats[i + 1].size) {
      stats[i] = stats[i + 1];
      stats[i + 1] = tmp;
    }
  }

  return stats;
}

function generateData(arr, order) {
  let stats = [];
  let assignment = [];

  let newArr = [];
  
  for(let i = 0; i< arr.length; i++) {
    newArr.push(arr[i])
  }


  order.filter((orderItem) => {
    newArr.map((sizeItem, index) => {
      const isAvaibleAssigment = assignment.find((assignteItem) => assignteItem.id === orderItem.id);

      if (isAvaibleAssigment) {
        return sizeItem;
      }

      if (orderItem.size.includes(sizeItem.size)) {

        if (sizeItem.quantity === 0) {
          return sizeItem;
        }

        assignment.push({
          id: orderItem.id,
          size: sizeItem.size,
          quantity: 1
        })

        const findedStatIndex = stats.findIndex((itemStat) => itemStat.size === sizeItem.size);

        if (findedStatIndex >= 0) {
          stats[findedStatIndex].quantity++;
        } else {
          stats.push({
            size: sizeItem.size,
            quantity: 1
          })
        }

        sizeItem.quantity--;
      }

      return sizeItem;
    });
  });

  stats = bubbleSort(stats)

  return {
    stats,
    assignment
  };
}


function getData(store, order) {

  if (store.length === 0 || order.length === 0) {
    return false;
  }
  
  const storee = store.values();
  
  const {
    stats,
    assignment
  } = generateData([...storee], order)

  console.log('store', store);


  return {
    stats,
    assignment
  };
}


console.log(getData(
  [{
    size: 1,
    quantity: 2
  }, {
    size: 2,
    quantity: 1
  }],
  [{
    id: 102,
    size: [2]
  }, {
    id: 103,
    size: [1]
  }, {
    id: 104,
    size: [1]
  }]
))
```

[Решение здесь jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nLqrpu9m/209/)

Comment: Только клонировать его. Можете сами вручную написать или использовать библиотеку lodash например

Comment: Об [Object.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) знаем?

Comment: Не работает, все ровно с freeze мутирует

Comment: @eccs0103, `Object.freeze()` фиксирует состав ствойств объекта, но никак не влияет на значения. Значения по-прежнему можно менять.

Comment: Запретить модификацию объектов невозможно. Если вы хотите "свои" объекты предохранить от порчи чужим кодом никогда не показывайте их в интерфейсе. Делайте копии.

Answer (score 0):

#### Объяснение

Чтобы массив не менялся у нас 2 проблемы.

1. Запретить изменение массива целиком.
2. Не дать изменить элементы массива.

Ответы на эти вопросы:

1. [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)
2. [Object.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)

#### Решение

Создадим константный массив и заморозим её:

```js
const readOnlyArray = Object.freeze([1, 2, 3]);
console.log(`До изменения: ${readOnlyArray}`);
try {
  readOnlyArray = null; // При попытке изменить константу выскакивает ошибка
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error.message);
}
readOnlyArray[0] = 5; // При попытке изменить элемент ошибки не будет, но и элемент изменить не удастся
console.log(`После изменения: ${readOnlyArray }`);
```

Comment: Как const поможет не мутировать массив?

Comment: const newArr = Object.freeze(store);

  const {
    stats,
    assignment
  } = generateData(newArr, order)

не работает

Comment: Object.freeze() Замораживает объект. А как его отсортировать(допустим) и вернуть новый отсортированный массив? Все равно возвращаемся к клонированию объектов.

Comment: есть примеры? не могу найти что-то

Comment: `freeze` морозит только верхний уровень, если в массиве будут объекты - их все так же можно будет изменить

Comment: @Aslero вы передаете замороженный массив в функцию, где создается *новый массив* на основе этой. Новый массив не будет заморожен. Вам надо заморозить массив при выходе из функции. Попробуйте так: `return { Object.freeze(stats), Object.freeze(assignment) };`

Comment: помогло let newArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(store));

Comment: @Aslero заморозить весь массив, то есть и массив, и элементы, и свойства объектов в элементах, и свойства объектов в объектах в элементах..., у вас просто так не получится. Надо будет рекурсивно заморозить и то будут объекты к примеру `Proxy` которые выдадут конфликт.